# iggrid page size drop down list showed and disappeared, it cannot be selected on IE10 and IE11

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

The iggrid shows up correctly.  But it cannot be changed page size because the drop down list showed after mouse click and disappeared when mouse move to select.

I am using iggrid 13.1.20131.2217.

My feature code :

```
.Features( features =>
{
    features.Sorting().Type(OpType.Local);
    features.Paging().Type(OpType.Local).Inherit(true).PageSize(10);
    features.Selection().Mode(SelectionMode.Row);
    features.Filtering();
    features.ColumnMoving().Mode(MovingMode.Deferred).AddMovingDropdown(true).MoveType(MovingType.Render);
})
```

IE shows error when mouse move over button and text box of page size change:
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space
File: infragistics.ui.editors.js, Line: 3307, Column: 13

Thanks in advance
Wilson

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin Pavlov of Infragistics.

The answer is [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/84206.aspx).